# Unable to ssh to instance after changing port

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have a running EC2 instance on which one of the database having transactional records stored through the application running on the same instance. I've change the port due to some security reasons but after changing port I'm unable to SSH to the instance.

My security group and NACL both having old as well as new port configured in it.
I've tried to SSH several times but it gives error `Network Error: Connection timeout`.
I'm scared about to data lost if this instance gets stopped. Need help!

Comment: The new port could be blocked by the firewall

Comment: did you change your SSH port or some other?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I don't have any software or hardware firewall configured and I've only change the SSH port under the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.

Comment: You say that you are "scared about to data lost if this instance gets stopped". Is your instance using Instance Store (temporary disk storage) or Amazon EBS storage? If it is Amazon EBS, there is no danger in losing data if the instance is stopped. Worst case, you can stop the instance, put the disk on another instance to reset your configuration change, put the disk back and things should be working. It would be similar to: [Recover Access to EC2 Instances After Losing SSH Key Pair](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/recover-access-lost-key-pair/)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I'm using Amazon EBS storage but I can't stop EC2 instance as it has database which records transactional records for every minute/second.

Comment: Well, if the instance contains your application and your database and you can't login to it, you'll need some down-time to regain access. Can you show us the command you are trying to use to login to it on a different port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can login to instance without losing data with the help of 'session manager' option under the "System Manager". You will need to complete certain per-requisites of the session manager as follows given in the Amazon docs for [Systems Manager Prerequisites](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-prereqs.html)

1. After completing the per-requisites assign the IAM role to the EC2 instance created for SSM.
2. Into the AWS console, search for the session manager option under the System manager and your instance ID will get listed over there.
3. Select the instance and choose for the Start session, you will get the shell console of your instance.
4. Revert the changes made in /etc/ssh/sshd_config for the port and try to SSH again.